# How to Use LDAP authenitication in opscenter for individual users to give admin access instead of a group?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, opscenter

Is it possible to grant access to individual users admin access to opscenter using LDAP (AD authentication) instead of a group.

If yes how can configure it ?? I am using Opscenter 5.2.4

Comment: I think this question belongs in serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

> When an LDAP user has been assigned LDAP roles, exactly one of those roles must also exist in OpsCenter, otherwise the user cannot log in to OpsCenter.

From http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opscenter/opsc/configure/createRoleForLDAPUser.html

Also see http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opscenter/opsc/configure/secOpscLdapOverview.html for general LDAP setup and troubleshooting.